# How to create a one to one relationship from table editior using foreign keys in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I am trying to set up a bunch of foreign key's in MySQL Workbench. It all seems to be working fine except that when I reverse engineer the EER diagram the relationship is always coming up as one to many rather than one to one. For my purposes I need to establish both types in different tables and I was wandering what I can do to control the type of relationship when I set up the foreign key.
Sorry if I am completely missing something obvious / basic but I am a beginner at this. Below I have included a screen shot of my current set-up of a foreign key that I want to result in a one to one relationship but is currently giving me a one to many. All help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A 1:1 relationhip can be defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255)  
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    OtherDetails VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Table1(ID)
);
```

To insert a record into Table2, the ID value must be present in Table1 (the Table2 foreign key constraint enforces this) and can only be added to Table2 once (Primary key constraint enforces this)